# Getting reference of forked state machines from original state machine in spring

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am using spring state machine and have configured fork and join in that state machine. Can I get the reference of newly forked state machines in some way because I want to persist those forked machines as well. I have checked that DefaultStateMachineExecutor has started the forked machines. Can this bean or any other we can use?

Comment: Can you include some code to show how you've implemented this?

Comment: I have referred following spring state machine documentation https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/statemachine-examples-tasks.html
It creates forked/child state machines. Now if I send event to original machine then it will send it to respective forked machine, but is there a way in which I can get reference to forked machines so that I can persist them.

Comment: You mean you've forked the *tasks*?